# How to make wxWidgets password visible, I am using 'wxTE_PASSWORD' flag?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using wxWIdgets to show a textbox and using

```
m_passwordText = new wxTextCtrl(m_panel, wxID_ANY, wxT(""), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, wxDefaultSize.GetHeight()), wxTE_PASSWORD);
```

I want to make this text visible sometimes and sometimes invisible(black dots). Is there any way that I can achieve this ?

Comment: I don't think this style can be set dynamically. The best way is to re-create the control. Check the widgets sample for details on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wxWidgets 3.0 manual, you can do it with wxGTK but not wxMSW (windows).

WIth GTK, to dynamically change a textbox style, you can do something like this:

```
textbox->SetWindowStyle(wxTE_PASSWORD);
textbox->Refresh();
```

On Windows, it looks like there is a backdoor way to change it, with this:

```
bool hidepwd = true;
HWND hwnd = (HWND) textbox->GetHandle();
SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, hidepwd ? 0x25cf: 0, 0); // 0x25cf is ● character
textbox->Refresh();
```

There's an old discussion of doing this on the wxWidgets forum here: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=15093